# can we wait job until previous job get finished in python or pyspark?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyspark, multiprocessing, threadpool

I am trying to run Jobs in parallel manner but problem is some jobs are dependent to others. If I trigger them simultaneously then dependent jobs will fail. So What I am thinking dependent jobs will wait until parents jobs finished completely. Is there any way to do this?

Example:

```
Job       Job_Type
A         independent
B         independent
C         A
D         B
```

In above example you can see job A & B are independent so they will run simultaneously but C & D are dependent on A & B respectively. So C will immediately start after completion of A and D will immediately start after completion of B. Can we make this kind of process?

In my code I am categories based on sequence number-

```
Job       Job_Type      seq_num
A         independent    1
B         independent    1
C         A              2
D         B              2
```

First seq_num = 1 will trigger and all the jobs in seq_num 1 will run parallel. After completion of 1 seq_num 2 will start. So suppose Job A is taking 10 mins. and B is taking 15 mins so seq_num 2 will start after 15 mins But I want process Job C will start immediately completion of Job A means after 10 mins Job C will start and after 15 mins Job D will start. Please help me to implement this logic.

Code I am using:

```
def parallel_Execution():
    
    logging.info("parallel_Execution..................[started]")
    par_temp_loc = '/medaff/Temp/'

    '''Reading the metadata file and creating as a dataframe'''
    df = pd.read_csv(par_temp_loc+'metadata_file_imedical.txt', delimiter='|',error_bad_lines=False)
    uni_master_job = df['Master Job Name'].unique().tolist()
    print(uni_master_job)

    '''getting unique execution sequence'''
    logging.info("Getting the unique Execution Sequence Number!")
    unique_exec_seq = df['Execution Sequence'].unique().tolist()
    unique_exec_seq.sort()
    print(unique_exec_seq)
    num_unique_seq = len(unique_exec_seq)
    logging.info("Total Number of unique sequence Number : %2d" %(num_unique_seq))

    
    p2 = ThreadWithReturnValue(target = partial(parallel_temp2, unique_exec_seq, df ))
    p2.start()

    r2 = p2.join()
    print(r2)

    #r1 = r1.append(r2)
    mail_df(r2)

'''Parallel Processing Function'''
def parallel_temp2(unique_exec_seq, df):
    list_df = []
    df_main4 = pd.DataFrame()
    for exec_seq in unique_exec_seq:
        seq_num = exec_seq
        temp_df = df[df['Execution Sequence'] == exec_seq].copy()
        unique_master_job = temp_df['Master Job Name'].unique().tolist()
        print(unique_master_job)
        #logging.info("%s Master Job Started." %(unique_master_job))

        if(len(unique_master_job)>0):
                    
            num_processes = len(unique_master_job)
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=num_processes)
            result1 = pool.map(partial(parallel_view_creation, exec_seq, temp_df), unique_master_job)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            df_main = pd.DataFrame(result1)
            #print("printing df_main")
            #print(df_main)
                
            for m_job in df_main.master_job.unique():
                temp_df1 = df_main[df_main['master_job'] == m_job]
                status = temp_df1.status.unique()[0]
                if(status == 0):
                    unique_master_job.remove(m_job)

            pool = ThreadPool(processes=num_processes)
            result2 = pool.map(partial(parallel_build_query, exec_seq, temp_df), unique_master_job)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            if(result2):                
                df_main2 = pd.DataFrame(result2)

            df_main3 = pd.concat([df_main,df_main2], sort = False)
            status_df_list = df_main3['status'].unique().tolist()
            print(status_df_list)
            if(0 in status_df_list):
                break
        if(0 in status_df_list):
            break
        else:
            df_main4 = df_main4.append(df_main3)
    if(0 in status_df_list):
        df_main4 = df_main4.append(df_main3)
                
    return df_main4
```

Please let me know if you need any information.

Answer (score 0):

Threading in python is not parallel processing of data as python has a concept called GIL which in the end performs the operations sequentially only.

One way and a better way to code this is

1. Segregate your all four requirements.
2. Download and install [airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/)
3. Create good looking workflows and easily maintainable too using the DAG.

This can also be used to standardize your process.